# How can I find out how much space is overflowing with jquery?

Tags: jquery, rotation, space, auto

What I want to do is to find out how much space an absolute element inside a div element extends out of the main element.

[I drew as an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtxS6.png)

In the example, I need to find the number of pixels in the area I marked with the box and reset it to the right border.

My goal is for the dropdown element to align itself when it overflows.

Very happy if you help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function something like getOverlappingBounds that takes two selectors/dom notes to compare.

```
function getOverlappingBounds(node, referenceNode) {
   var boundsToCompare = node.getBoundingClientRect();
   var boundsOfReference = referenceNode.getBoundingClientRect();

   return {
     bottom: boundsOfReference.bottom - boundsToCompare.bottom,
     left: boundsToCompare.left - boundsOfReference.left,
     right: boundsOfReference.right - boundsToCompare.right,
     top: boundsToCompare.top - boundsOfReference.top,
   }
}
```

Then, I can use it as `getOverlappingBounds(document.querySelector("#node2"), document.querySelector("#node1"))`

- A negative value for a property means it is beyond the bounds.
- A positive value would imply that it's within.
- A 0 value means that it shares an edge.